# How to programmatically set iphone keyboard to show desired key set

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uikeyboardtype, iphone-keypad

I am programming an iPhone app that I want a text field where the user can add numbers from the keyboard and add them on the fly, ie, the user might type "1.5+2.4+6.3+.063" and as the user types additional numbers and plus signs the total is displayed immediately.

The problem is starting on and keeping the keyboard in the `123` mode after the user types a + sign (using email keyboard because it has the numbers and the plus sign on the same view).

How can I start the email keyboard on the _123 screen and keep it there?

Thanks! Mike

Comment: Did the answers help? Please select the answer that was correct... If not, please comment to let us know how it was not helpful. :)

Comment: Helped me though :) thanks!

Answer (score 9):

use below code to set the keyboard type

```
myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

All the keyboard type is define in [UITextInputTraits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType) protocol, which is implemented by [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what textfield you want to set it for you go:

```
[textField setKeyboardType:(UIKeyboardType)];
```

Where UIKeyboardType could be any of the following: [UIKeyboardTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType)

***EDIT

In your case you would do:

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
```

***EDIT

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I want to use the UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress but have the app start with the numeric portion showing and stay on that. Initially, the keyboard starts with the alphabetic characters and the user has to press the [_123] button to get to the numbers, but I want to start on the numbers and stay there even when the '+' button is pressed (normally it returns to the alphabet characters.

Comment: See the edit... The keyboard type you're looking for is UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation . How to use it is in the edited part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, I could not find a way to programmatically change keyboard modes to `123` or `#+=`.

But if you want the default keyboard start as if user had pressed the `123` button on keypad, your only choice is:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
```

Here is how `numbersAndPunctuation` keypad will be presented

[image]

Other related/useful keypad types are:

```
textField.keyboardType =.numberPad
```

[image]

```
textField.keyboardType =.decimalPad
```

[image]

```
textField.keyboardType =.phonePad
```

[image]